# Convert array to int

Tags: c, arrays

How do I convert an `uint8_t array[2]` to an `uint16_t value`

I am reading two bytes of data from an i2c device into an array and have to convert that to an integer to perform conversions on the data.

```
static int i2cRead(uint8_t *buffer, uint32_len, uint16_t addr);

static uint16_t readVaue(uint8_t reg) {
    uint8_t buff[2];
    i2cWrite(&buff, sizeof(buff), I2CADDR)
    buffer = // STUCK HERE
}
```

Comment: `value = ((uint16_t)(array[0])<<8) + array[1];` or `value = ((uint16_t)(array[1])<<8) + array[0];` it depends on the endianness.

Comment: What is the endianness of these two bytes (that together are a 16 bit integer, e.g. Least Significant Byte, Most Significant Byte)? What is the endianness of the machine receiving these two bytes (e.g. MSB, LSB)? You might only need a cast.

Comment: Is the reading function really called `i2cWrite`?

Comment: FYI: My I2C experience is that the address was always _big endian_.  So, _in general_, I would expect the I2C data to also be the same endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) 
{
    uint8_t array[] = {0xAA, 0x55};

    // Big endian conversion
    uint16_t value = ((uint16_t)(array[0])<<8) + array[1];

    printf("%X\n", value);

    // Little endian conversion
    value = ((uint16_t)(array[1])<<8) + array[0];

    printf("%X\n", value);

}
```

Comment: Nice choice of sample values.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to shift the high byte over by 8 bits, and do a logical OR with the low order bits.  Also, make sure to cast each value to `uint16_t` first, otherwise your risk the shifted values being truncated:

```
uint8_t buff[2];
i2cWrite(&buff, sizeof(buff), I2CADDR)
uint16_t value = 0;
value |= (uint16_t)buff[0] << 8;
value |= (uint16_t)buff[1];
```

Comment: Why not just `buff[0] * 256U + buff[1]`  (putting endianness aside here)?

Comment: @alk It is another solution. Post it. I don't think it is better or worse then using shift operator.

Comment: @alk To me at least, it's more clear to use shifts and bitwise AND/OR rather than arithmetic operations, given the nature of the function to be performed.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on endianness do

```
... = 256U * buff[0] + buff[1];
```

or

```
... = 256U * buff[1] + buff[0];
```